# OpenCV-python get pixel set in between two points (line)

Tags: python, opencv

I am try to retrieve pixel set of  two point in-between (line)

i suspect that function `cvSampleLine()` in the openCV could use for the task,

is it correct ? if so can anyone point out simple python example for that ?

Comment: `LineIterator` is the C++ alternative for that. Unfortunately neither of those two is available in Python. But have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32328179/3962537) for a possible alternative.

Comment: thanks man.... (y)

Comment: Just posted a super simple one-liner for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59525697/5339857