# Can cv2.polylines return the coordinates of every point that form the line?

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV Python API has a method called [`cv2.polylines`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.polylines), just like this.

Some example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im = np.zeros((1000,900), dtype="uint8")
coords = [[0,0], [0,500],[500,500]]
coords_array = np.array([coords], dtype=np.int32)
cv2.polylines(im, coords_array, 1, 255)
cv2.imshow('image',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Can OpenCV return all the points that form the triangle that I draw rather than three vertices? I know an algorithm called [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) is built for this purpose, but I don't know if OpenCV has this algorithm implemented in its `cv2.polyline` method. And so I don't know the set of points I get from Bresenham's line algorithm is the same as the outline of triangle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV 3.0 LineIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328179/opencv-3-0-lineiterator)

Comment: This maybe the thing I needed, thank you.@Georgy